# How to use case statement inside an SQL select Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, case

I need to get the output of a selected query depending on certain conditions

Means `if(id=uid)` 
then I need the below query

```
select * from table1 where id=5;
```

else 
I need the below one

```
select * from table1 where id=10
```

I know i can use if condition for this. But my query is very long one so when I use if else then it would look like

```
if(@id=@uid)
begin
select * from table1 where id=5;// query 1
end
else
select * from table1 where id=10;//query 2
```

but here I need to replace the entire query once again for a single check. I hope I can do something like this:

```
declare @id int=4;
declare @uid=10;

select * from table1 where 
case 
when @id=@uid
then 
id=5
else
id=10;
end
```

**Updation**

I need one more condition too

in this case id=5 and uid=10

```
then if(id=uid)
```

then

```
select * from table1 where id=5
```

and

```
if(id!=uid)
```

then

```
select * from table1
```

something like this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `case` expression to return the value `id` should be equal to:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1 
WHERE  id = CASE WHEN @id = @uid THEN 5 ELSE 10 END;
```

EDIT:

The updated requirement in the question is to return all rows when `@id != @uid`. This can be done by comparing `id` to `id`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1 
WHERE  id = CASE WHEN @id = @uid THEN 5 ELSE id END;
```

Alternatively, with this updated requirement, a simple `or` expression might be simpler to use:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1 
WHERE  @id = @uid OR id = 5;
```

Comment: wonderfull answer .. i need little more help too.. how can i select when id=uid then id=5 and when id!=uid then select * from table1 like wise

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV I don't understand what you mean by "when id!=uid then select * from table1 like wise". Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    table1
WHERE
(
    @id = @uid
    AND
    id =5
)
OR
(
    not @id = @uid
    AND
    id=10
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE (id=5 AND @id=@uid) OR (id=10 AND @id<>@uid)
```